# Spring MongoDB authorization failed

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have an issue with `Spring MongoDB` authorization process - attempts to retrieve data via `REST API` led to response:

```
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException",
"message": "Failed to authenticate to database [testdb], username = [test_user], password = [t**t]"
```

I have installed and configured `MongoDB`. This is my `MongoDB` config file:

```
systemLog:  
    destination: file  
    logAppend: true  
    path: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data\log\mongod.log  
    timeStampFormat: iso8601-utc  

storage:
    dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data\db  
    journal:  
        enabled: true  

processManagement:  
    # fork: true  
    pidFilePath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\mongod.pid  

net:  
    port: 27017  
    bindIp: 127.0.0.1

security:
    authorization: enabled
```

Next step I have created admin user and user for `testdb` database:

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> db.createUser({user: "admin", pwd: "qwerty", roles: ["root"]})
Successfully added user: { "user" : "admin", "roles" : [ "root" ] }
> use testdb
switched to db testdb
> db.createUser({user: "test_user", pwd: "test", roles: [{role: "readWrite", db: "testdb"}]})
Successfully added user: {
        "user" : "test_user",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "readWrite",
                        "db" : "testdb"
                }
        ]
}
```

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-rest-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- Enable Java 8 -->
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
        <mockito.version>1.9.5</mockito.version>
        <assertj.version>1.7.0</assertj.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!-- Configure the main class of our Spring Boot application -->
        <start-class>org.wixanz.App</start-class>
    </properties>

    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Get the dependencies of a web application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Data MongoDB-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Util -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Spring Boot Maven Support -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Java MongoDB configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:mongodb.properties")
public class MongoDBConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {

        UserCredentials userCredentials = new UserCredentials(env.getProperty("mongodb.username"),  env.getProperty("mongodb.password"));
        MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient(env.getProperty("mongodb.host"),  Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("mongodb.port")));
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, env.getProperty("mongodb.db"), userCredentials);
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }

}
```

`MongoDB.properties` file in project:

```
mongodb.host=localhost
mongodb.port=27017
mongodb.db=testdb
mongodb.username=test_user
mongodb.password=test
```

If I try to connect to `testdb` database without implementation of `UserCredential` than the connection established successfully and data received.

What I need to correct that database authorize connection passed successfully?

Answer (score 0):

```
Connect to mongoDb
```

mongo 127.0.0.1:27017

Create User
Go to mongoDB console and delete your current user & set authSchema version to 3 instead of 5 , 
follow these commands in mongo console -

mongo use admin

db.system.users.remove({})    <== removing all users

db.system.version.remove({}) <== removing current version

db.system.version.insert({ "_id" : "authSchema", "currentVersion" : 3 })

Create User:

use test-dev-db

db.createUser(
   {
     user: "root",
     pwd: "bnuy93JoLJjiop",
     roles: [ "readWrite", "dbAdmin" ]
   }
  )